# Cannnot Assign- must be a instance Django

Tags: django

I have a table called job_position and there is a foreign key called region.

```
position =job_position.objects.get(id=position_id)
position.department= department.objects.get(department_name =request.POST.get("department")),
```

the "department" is passed from the HTML form, and the value of it is "Asia"

I am quite sure the error is from the second line

`Cannot assign "(<region: Asia>,)": "job_position.region" must be a "region" instance.`

But when I am trying the code in python shell ,it works fine,ie.e can get the region object and pass it to the position object region attribute and works fine. But somehow it does not works in the web development. 
Anyone can help explain? Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cannot assign "(<region: Asia>,)"`

As you have a comma at the end of your line, it turned it object into a tuple. Simply remove the comma:

```
position.department = department.objects.get(department_name=request.POST.get("department"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @chris-morgan, but I was hoping to show the OP where the comma was so have them remove it themselves.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: I assumed when you said "Simply remove the comma" that you had intended to remove the comma in the line indicated. Sorry!